# SHIFT + ALT + D is not opening the Blazor WebAssembly debugger in Ubuntu

Tags: blazor-client-side

SHIFT + ALT + D is not opening the Blazor WebAssembly debugger in Chrome 79.0.3945.88 on Ubuntu Ubuntu 18.04.3.  I'm able to open the debugger when running the same project on Windows 10.  I checked and confirmed that keyboard setting is not currently taken by anything else in the Ubuntu system settings.  The project was launched with  `dotnet run --configuration Debug`.  Keyboard focus is in the Blazer app.  Anyone have any other suggestions or know if this is a known limitation?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work using http instead of https. Here are the steps that worked:

1. In a terminal navigate to the folder named `server` in the project
2. Launch the project in debug mode with the command `dotnet run --configuration debug`
3. In a different terminal window launch Chrome with the following command.  Change paths as appropriate on your system.
4. `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="/WhateverPathYouWantHere" http://localhost:5000`
5. Now in Chrome you should be able to SHIFT + ALT + D to open the debugger tab and be able to navigate to your source files.